# C - array function evaluation

Tags: c, arrays, performance, blas

Aloha! I am working in `C` and I'm using basic functions on all elements of an array with a `for` loop and I was wondering if it's possible to speed up this calculation (e.g. with `cblas` functions). I am using the following libraries (and would prefer to not add any as this project is not completely in my control):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_statistics_double.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <cblas.h>
#include <float.h>
```

The piece of code in question is this:

```
#use the following functions on every element of the array and add them together
for(ii = 0; ii < k1; ii++) { 
  val += t[ii]*x[ii] - log(1 + exp(x[ii]));
}
```

where `x` is a double-array of length `k1` I computed with `cblas_dgemv` (which does matrix-vector multiplication) and `t` is a double-array of the same length containing only `0` and `1` (not sparse). Now I am using basic functions on those entries and adding them together.

Questions:

1. Is there anything similar to `cblas_dgemv` for these non-linear functions (`exp` and `log`) that speeds up this process?
2. Can I make this calculation faster by using only the non-linear functions in a loop, storing the results and then using `cblas` functions again as much as possible?

Comment: If this is intended to run on a specific architecture, you could use SIMD instructions to stream some of those operations.  For example, Intel Intrinsics or similar.  Or enable vectorization in your compiler settings.  Depending on the nature of the calculation, you may also be able to split it into multiple worker threads.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't. It is supposed to run on a cluster computer but also on local machines with rather general settings/restrictions.

Comment: @tehfurbolg - I have a few questions. What C compiler do you have for the project? It might be gcc, but this is actually what I have :) If you want speed these days without any parallelism, then you are telling a joke, not asking a programming question. Pthreads, OpenMPI are standard nowadays.

Comment: I am using gcc, yes. Before I changed it, the calculation of the array x was hard-coded matrix-vector multiplication and using the cblas function made it a lot quicker already (also in other more complicated parts). but for this non-linear part I had no idea how to speed them up and was wondering if there was a similar solution. that's why I thought of this as a programming question and not a technical one.

Answer (score 0):

Your computation is more like a BLAS level 1 operation.
`ddot` of `x` and `t` in the first phrase and a reduction on the log part.

The answer would be yes if you would like to use BLAS. However it is not as efficient as BLAS L3 by nature. With some parallel implementation of them it might save you some time and effort though.